# nginx rewrite url problem need help

Tags: proxy, nginx, url-rewriting

I am new to nginx, and I have installed php (using port 8888) and nginx (using port 80), and I have a static html page as www.aa.com:8888/news/html/about/aboutus/index.html, now I would like to use www.aa.com/test/aboutus.html to visit it, and when doing this, the URL in the browser should not change. How to do this?

I tried some ways, but the link in the browser will just redirect to the new URL string ...

My sample config in the conf file of nginx as below:

```
    location ^~ /test/aboutus.html {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_redirect   default;
        rewrite ^/test/aboutus.html$ /news/html/about/aboutus last;
        break;
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody else has answered, so I guess I will give it a shot.

According to [the documentation for proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass):

> A special case is using variables in the proxy_pass statement: The requested URL is not used and you are fully responsible to construct the target URL yourself.

So if you can get a variable in there, you can just provide the full URL and not worry about `rewrite`.  Something like this:

```
location /test/aboutus.html {
    proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:8888/news/html/about/aboutus;
}
```

I have not tested this (sorry).

[update]

One more idea:

```
location /test/aboutus.html {
    proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:8888/news/html/about/aboutus;
    proxy_redirect $scheme://127.0.0.1:8888/news/html/about/aboutus $scheme://$host/test/aboutus.html
}
```

The idea is to map the Location header in the reply back to what you want the client to show in the browser.  That is what `proxy_redirect` is for (although the "default" setting should have worked I think).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tested, in my local env, the URL in the browser will just change from http://localhost/test/aboutus.html to http://127.0.0.1:8888/news/html/about/aboutus , not sure if it is my nginx env issue... 
I just want the URL will not change at all ...

Comment: Really?  Even without the `rewrite` rule?  That is very strange...

Comment: yes, exactly copy what you have written above. And I am testing on windows xp.

Comment: I have added one update.  I am sorry that I am unable to test this...

Comment: Nemo, thank you so much for your kind help. 
I also tested your update, unfortunately the URL in the browser still changed, and I tested under centOS, the same symptom... :(